# NDSolve emitting dvnoarg error

Tags: equation-solving, syntax

I'm trying to solve this simple system of ODEs, but it gives me the error "The function v1 appears with no arguments". I've attached a screenshot of the code. I hope someone could help me, I really can't understand what's wrong.

[image]

This is the code:

```
b = 0.2; a = 1.5; h1 = 0.2; L = 4; Young = 3*10^7; y = 0.1; ν = 0.2; q = -10;

equ1 = 
  {Derivative[4][v1][t] == 
     (12*L^3*
        (q + (-1/2*(2 - 2*a)^2*b*h1^3*(a*(L - 2*t) + 2*t)*Young*Derivative[2][v1][t])/L^3 + 
        (-1/2*(2 - 2*a)*b*h1^3*(a*(L - 2*t) + 2*t)^2*Young*Derivative[3][v1][t])/L^3))/
          (b*h1^3*(a*(L - 2*t) + 2*t)^3*Young), 
   Derivative[4][v2][t] == (12*q)/(b*h1^3*Young), 
   v1[0] == 0, 
   Derivative[1][v1][0] == 0, 
   v1[-1/2*L] == v2[-1/2*L], 
   Derivative[1][v1][-1/2*L] == Derivative[1][v2][-1/2*L], 
   Derivative[2][v1][-1/2*L] == Derivative[2][v2][-1/2*L], 
   (v1^3)[-1/2*L] == Derivative[3][v2][-1/2*L], 
   Derivative[2][v2][L] == 0, 
   Derivative[3][v2][L] == 0}

nsol = NDSolve[equ1, {v1[t], v2[t]}, {t, 0, L}]
```

Comment: I don't see the curly brackets in equ1....

Comment: Ok now I understand. I've already tried, but for me this version doesn't work as the previous one.

Comment: In order to help you we need real code, not an image.

Comment: Just get rid of the `(v1^3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted code cleaned up:

```
equ1 = {Derivative[4][v1][t] == (12 L^3 
  (q - ((2 - 2 a)^2 b h1^3 (a (L - 2 t) + 2 t) Young 
   Derivative[2][v1][t])/(2 L^3) -
  ((2 - 2 a) b h1^3 (a (L - 2 t) + 2 t)^2 Young 
   Derivative[3][v1][t])/(2 L^3)))/(b h1^3 (a (L - 2 t) + 2 t)^3 Young), 
   Derivative[4][v2][t] == (12 q)/(b h1^3 Young), v1[0] == 0, 
   Derivative[1][v1][0] == 0, v1[L/2] == v2[L/2], 
   Derivative[1][v1][L/2] == Derivative[1][v2][L/2], 
   Derivative[3][v1][L/2] == Derivative[3][v2][L/2], 
   Derivative[2][v2][L/2] == Derivative[2][v1][L/2], 
   Derivative[2][v2][L] == 0, Derivative[3][v2][L] == 0};

b = 0.2; a = 1.5; h1 = 0.2; L = 4; Young = 3*10^7; 
y = 0.1; \[Nu] = 0.2; q = -10;
nsol = NDSolve[equ1, {v1[t], v2[t]}, {t, 0, L}]
(* {{v1[t]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,4.}},<>][t],
    v2[t]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,4.}},<>][t]}} *)

Plot[Evaluate[{v1[t], v2[t]} /. nsol], {t, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{v1[t], v2[t]} /. nsol], {t, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Great! I hoped it was a syntax problem :)

Comment: Valentina, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.  Please (1) Read the [faqs](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) (2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the [gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the [checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)